# How to substitute filename on reading or opening new file

Tags: vimscript, filetype

We have rather complex file structure and I would like simplify opening file independently where am I in the filesystem at the moment.

Let's say we have a `project_folder` and several files in it:

```
  /project_folder/common-prefix/foo.txt
  /project_folder/common-prefix/bar.txt
  /project_folder/common-prefix/nested/zoo.txt
```

Usually I change to `project_folder/common-prefix` and work from it. Some command and documentation usually expose full relative project path, e.g. `common-prefix/bar.txt`

In this case I have to manually remove `common-prefix` to modify interested file. How can I configure vim so that opening a file it's file name would be processed and known prefixes would be removed/replaced?

```
$ cd /project_folder/common-prefix/
$ vim foo.txt # this works naturally
$ vim common-prefix/foo.txt # here I want to cut `common-prefix`
$ vim ../common-prefix/foo.txt # probably I want to convert to absolute path, but this is a corner case
```

I read about `includeexpr`, but it seems it olny works for `gf` commands, whereas I want something like `BufRead`/`BufNewFile`

I found similar questions:

- [Modify the path of a file be opened](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26466/modify-the-path-of-a-file-be-opened)
- [How to edit file name under cursor in Vim/Gvim, when it starts with /cygdrive/ in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398460/how-to-edit-file-name-under-cursor-in-vim-gvim-when-it-starts-with-cygdrive-i)

And also two plugins, which probably close to the implementation I want:

- [vim-fetch](https://github.com/wsdjeg/vim-fetch)
- [file-line](https://github.com/bogado/file-line)

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish... What's wrong with opening `/root_folder/foo.txt`, that's a valid path after all... Is the issue the path attached to the buffer (when you use `:ls` to list buffers, or the path shown in the status line)? Does it help if you `:cd` to the directory where the file is inside Vim? Do you want to change the behavior for paths listed in the command-line arguments, or for using the `:e` and similar commands inside Vim, or both? Please be more specific about the actual issue you're having, with realistic examples if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Btw, please [edit] the question to add more details. (Don't just answer in the comments.) Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, sorry for messy explanation. I tried my best to make it clear. Most likely this is something trivial, but I work with vimscript very rarely, so it's hard to know where to start. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to play with `BufNewFile`:

```
augroup test_prefix | au!
    au BufNewFile common_prefix/* :e <afile>:t
augroup END
```

In the example above, if you are in `..../common_prefix/` directory and do `vim text.txt` or `vim common_prefix/test.txt`
you will end up editing `test.txt` in the current directory.

Comment: Also worth checking `if filereadable(<afile>)` (possibly need `expand()`?), so you can edit an existing file normally.

Comment: This doesn't work for netsted files :|  `common-prefix/nested/zoo.txt`

Comment: 'Nested' is not in the question. Try adding `**/*` instead of `*`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an actual answer, more like an attempt. I saw something similar was done in [vim-vp4](https://github.com/ngemily/vim-vp4) plugin:

```
func! s:openPrefixedFile(fname)
    echom "function is called with " . a:fname
    let l:oldBufname = bufname('%')
    let l:newFile = substitute(a:fname, "common-prefix/", "", "")
    echom "new filename is " . l:newFile
    echom "buf number is " . bufnr('%')

    execute 'bdelete! ' . l:oldBufname
    execute 'edit ' . l:newFile
    execute 'buffer ' . bufnr('%')
    execute 'doauto BufRead'
endfunc

augroup test_prefix | au!
    au BufNewFile common-prefix/* call s:openPrefixedFile(expand('%:p'))
augroup END
```

This work with single file, but doesn't support `-O/-o` options for splitting multiple files :(